# Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input APEX 5.1

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have this problem: 
I have this JavaScript code in a Dynamic Action:

```
var vMe     = $(this.triggeringElement);
var vRow    = $(vMe).parents(".meAllRow");
var vSeqID  = $(vRow).find("[headers=SEQ_ID]").html();
var vEstado = $(vRow).find("[name=f01]").val();

apex.server.process("ajx_Cambia_estado",{x01:vSeqID,x02:vEstado});
```

and this is the PL-SQL CODE

```
DECLARE

vEstado VARCHAR2(1);
vSeq    NUMBER := to_number(APEX_APPLICATION.g_x01);
BEGIN   
        IF (APEX_APPLICATION.g_x02 = 'A') THEN
            vEstado := 'I';
        ELSE
            vEstado := 'A';
        END IF;

        APEX_COLLECTION.UPDATE_MEMBER (
        p_collection_name => 'DINAMIC_LIST',
        p_seq  => vSeq,
        p_c002 => vEstado);   

END;
```

When I execute the dynamic action, it throws this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON

but when I put a return in the PL-SQL like:

```
htp.p('"process":"finish"');
```

the error disappears. But I don't need to send a response message, in Apex 4.2 I don't have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
DECLARE

vEstado VARCHAR2(1);
vSeq    NUMBER := to_number(APEX_APPLICATION.g_x01);

BEGIN   
        IF (APEX_APPLICATION.g_x02 = 'A') THEN
            vEstado := 'I';
        ELSE
            vEstado := 'A';
        END IF;

        APEX_COLLECTION.UPDATE_MEMBER (
        p_collection_name => 'DINAMIC_LIST',
        p_seq  => vSeq,
        p_c002 => vEstado);   

        apex_json.open_object;  
        apex_json.write('success', true);  
        apex_json.close_object; 

END;
```